# prevent browser url change when managing history

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, browser-history

Normally when we move from one section to another using ajax then history is not saved and that is why we can not click on browser back button. i am showing data in tabular format and also showing pager link so user can go to see next sets of data but initially history was not managed. i go through a tutorial and implement to save history forcefully by js library called `jquery.ba-bbq.min.js` this way

```
$(window).trigger('hashchange');

when people click on back/forward button then haschange function is firing

$(window).bind('hashchange', function (e) {
    var searchTerm = '';
    var pageIndex = e.getState("pageIndex") || 0;
    pageIndex = parseInt(pageIndex);
    searchTerm = e.getState("keyword") || '';
    if (searchTerm != null && searchTerm != '') {
        $("input[id*='txtSearch']").val(searchTerm);
        block();
        Search(searchTerm, pageIndex);
    }
});
```

this way calling `setHistory()` forcefully insert data to history when user click on pager link

```
calling setHistory(1, SearchTerm);

    function setHistory(pageIndex, SearchTerm) {
        $.bbq.pushState({ pageIndex: pageIndex, keyword: SearchTerm });
    }
```

my code works fine the problem is url is getting changed in browser address bar. **so i like to know is there any way to maintain history without changing url in address bar?**

if possible guide me how to do that or also can specify another library which will maintain history but address will not be changed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to be able to use the Back button, then no.
History is stored when doing a page load or changing the location hash.

Comment: in my case when we push anything into browser history then a # is added in the url. how can i get rid of?